# My website works only on safari. ie, chrome, and firefox are not recognizing my css

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, safari

When i open it in safari every thing seems to work fine but when i open it in chrome or ie or firefox the images show a missing image icon and my css colors and some styles are missing. also it works perfectly on safari but it work the same on ie and chrome but on firefox it just completely doesnt understand the code.  Here is my [Website](http://obhsmsa.host56.com)

And if you need my actual code

HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://static.dudamobile.com/DM_redirect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">DM_redirect("http://mobile.dudamobile.com/site/obhsmsa_host56");</script>

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon-1.ico" />
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="grid.css" type="text/css" media="screen">   
    <script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="cufon-replace.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Glegoo_400.font.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="FF-cash.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>      

</head>
<body id="page1">
    <!--==============================header=================================-->
    <header>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <h1><a href="index.html">OBHS MSA</a></h1>
                <nav class="fright">
                    <ul class="menu">
                        <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Disscussions.html">Discussion Question/Topics </a></li>
                        <li><a href="getinvolved.html">Get Involved</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Debates.html">Debates</a></li>
            <li><a href="leaders.html">Leaders </a></li>
                        <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div><br>
        </div>
        <div class="row-bot">
            <div class="main">
                <figure class="img-indent-r"><img src="/page1-img1.png" alt="" /></figure>
                <div class="extra-wrap indent">
                    <strong class="title-1">Welcome to Old Bridge High School MSA</strong>
                    <p> <p>Old Bridge High School MSA is one of the many MSA programs worldwide. MSA history "Established in January 1963, the Muslim Students Association of the U.S. & Canada (MSA National) continues to serve Muslim students during their college and university careers by facilitating their efforts to establish, maintain and develop local MSA chapters.

First established on the campus of the University of Illinois at Urbana-Champaign by a conference of Muslim students from around the U.S. and Canada, MSA National has been a uniting forum for Muslim students from diverse backgrounds for over four decades. It continues its mission of meeting the needs of our Muslim youth on campus with the zeal and energy of the Muslim students, but requires the support of the larger community." (MSA NATIONAL)</p>
                <br></div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <!--==============================content================================-->
    <section id="content"><div class="ic"></div>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="container_12">
                <div class="wrapper p3">
                    <article class="grid_4">
                        <div class="banner">
                            <figure><img src="/banner-1.png" alt="" /></figure><br>
                            <a class="button" href="http://msanational.org">more</a>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                    <article class="grid_4">
                        <div class="banner">
                            <figure><img src="/banner-2.png" alt="" /></figure><br>
                            <a class="button" href="http://icnany.org/site2/">more</a>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                    <article class="grid_4">
                        <div class="banner">
                            <figure><img src="/banner-3.png" alt="" /></figure><br>
                            <a class="button" href="#">more</a>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                </div>
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <article class="grid_8">
                        <h2>Upcoming Meetings</h2>
                        <div class="wrapper border-bot p3">
                            <time class="tdate-1" datetime="2012-10-21">
                                <span>Friday</span>
                                <strong>4</strong>
                            </time>
                            <div class="extra-wrap">
                                <p class="prev-indent-bot"><span class="color-1"></span></p>
                                <p>We will be staying till 4:00 inshAllah, after prayer we will be having a dissussion, or a possible special guest.</p>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="wrapper">
                            <time class="tdate-1" datetime="2012-10-21">
                                <span>Friday</span>
                                <strong>11</strong>
                            </time>

                            <div class="extra-wrap">
                                <span class="color-1"></span><p>We will be staying till 3:15.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                    <article class="grid_4">
                        <div class="indent-top">

                            <div class="indent-left p3">


                            </div>
                            <div class="box">
                                <div class="padding">
                                    <strong class="text-1">General Meetings</strong>
                                    <figure class="p2"></figure>
                                    <h6><strong>Friday 2:30 - 3:15</strong></h6>
                                    We have a khutbah than we have Friday prayer. Bus passes are provided. All are welcome.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!--==============================footer=================================-->
    <footer>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="container_12">  
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="grid_8">
                        <div class="aligncenter">
                            <br> <br>OBHS MSA, ALL RIGHTS RESERVED &copy; 2013
                           </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid_3 prefix_1">
                        <ul class="list-services">
                            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/145504852207555/"></a></li>
                            <li class="item-1"><a href="https://www.twitter.com/obhs_msa"></a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script type="text/javascript"> Cufon.now(); </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my css is

```
> /* Getting the new tags to behave */ article, aside, audio, canvas,
> command, datalist, details, embed, figcaption, figure, footer, header,
> hgroup, keygen, meter, nav, output, progress, section, source, video
> {display:block;} mark, rp, rt, ruby, summary, time {display:inline;}
> 
> /* Global properties
> ======================================================== */ html {width:100%; height:100%;}
> 
> body {font-family:Arial, Helvetica,
> sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:25px;color:#7f7f7f;min-width:1000px;height:100%;background:url(/body-tail.gif)
> center top repeat #0e0f0f;} .ic
> {border:0;float:right;background:#990099;color:#f00;width:50%;line-height:10px;font-size:10px;margin:-220%
> 0 0 0;overflow:hidden;padding:0} .bg {width:100%;
> background:url(/content-tail.gif) center 0 no-repeat;}
> 
> .main {   width:1000px;       margin:0 auto; }
> 
> a {color:#cc2800; outline:none;} a:hover {text-decoration:none;}
> 
> .col-1, .col-2 {float:left;}
> 
> .wrapper {width:100%; overflow:hidden;} .extra-wrap {overflow:hidden;}
> p {margin-bottom:22px;} .p1 {margin-bottom:8px;} .p2
> {margin-bottom:15px;} .p3 {margin-bottom:30px;} .p4
> {margin-bottom:40px;} .p5 {margin-bottom:50px;}
> 
> .reg {text-transform:uppercase;}
> 
> .fleft {float:left;} .fright {float:right;}
> 
> .alignright {text-align:right;} .aligncenter {text-align:center;}
> 
> .it {font-style:italic;}
> 
> .color-1 {color:#fff;} .color-2 {color:#000;} .color-3 {color:#666;}
> 
> /*********************************boxes**********************************/ .indent {padding:46px 0 0 30px;} .indent-top {padding-top:10px;}
> .indent-left {padding-left:20px;} .indent-right {padding-right:20px;}
> 
> .indent-bot {margin-bottom:20px;} .indent-bot2 {margin-bottom:18px;}
> .indent-bot3 {margin-bottom:45px;}
> 
> .prev-indent-bot {margin-bottom:10px;} .prev-indent-bot2
> {margin-bottom:5px;} .img-indent-bot {margin-bottom:25px;} .margin-bot
> {margin-bottom:35px;}
> 
> .img-indent {float:left; margin:0 20px 0px 0;}     .img-indent2
> {float:left; margin:0 13px 0px 0;}     .img-indent3 {float:left;
> margin:11px 20px 0px 0;} .img-indent-r {float:right; margin:-43px 0px
> 0px 30px;}    
> 
> .buttons a:hover {cursor:pointer;}
> 
> .menu li a, .list-1 a, .list-2 a, .link, .button, .button2, h1 a
> {text-decoration:none;}   
> 
> /*********************************header*************************************/ header {   width:100%;     background:#000;    position:relative; 
>   z-index:2; }
> 
> h1 {  padding:25px 0 24px 1px;    float:left; }   h1 a {
>       display:block;          width:458px;        height:94px;        text-indent:-9999em;
>       background:url(/logo.png) 0 0 no-repeat;    }    /***** menu *****/
> .menu {   padding:66px 29px 0 0;  } .menu li {    float:left; 
>   position:relative;  padding-left:28px; } .menu li a {
>   display:inline-block;   font-size:14px;     line-height:17px; 
>   color:#7f7f7f;  } .menu li a.active, .menu > li > a:hover
> {color:#cc2700;}
> 
> .row-bot {    width:100%;     padding: 0 0;
>   background:url(row-bot-tail.gif) center top repeat-x; } .title-1 {
>   display:block;  font-size:29px;     line-height:2em;    color:#fff;
>   letter-spacing:-2px;    margin-bottom:5px; }
> 
> /*********************************content*************************************/
> #content {    width:100%;     padding:40px 0 60px;    background:url(content-tail.gif) center top repeat;
>   position:relative;  z-index:1; }
> 
> .spacer-1 {   width:100%;     background:url(pic-1.gif) 217px 0 repeat-y;
> }
> 
> .box {    width:100%;     background:url(box-tail.gif) 0 0 repeat;
>   border-radius:5px;  -moz-border-radius:5px;
>   -webkit-border-radius:5px; }    .box .padding {padding:5px 20px 15px;}
> 
> h2 {  font-size:35px;     line-height:2em;    color:#fff;
>   letter-spacing:-3px; } h3 {     font-size:24px;     line-height:2em; 
>   color:#fff;     background:url(h3-tail.gif) 0 0 repeat;
>   border-radius:5px;  -moz-border-radius:5px;
>   -webkit-border-radius:5px;  padding-left:21px;  letter-spacing:-2px;
> } h6 {color:#fff; font-weight:normal;}
> 
> .border-bot {     width:100%;     padding-bottom:32px; 
>   background:url(pic-1.gif) 0 bottom repeat-x; }
> 
> .banner {     width:100%;     position:relative; }    .banner a {
>       position:absolute;      left:20px;      bottom:30px;    }
> 
> .button {     display:inline-block;   padding:1px 20px 8px;
>   font-size:18px;     line-height:22px;   color:#556502; 
>   background:url(button-tail.gif) 0 0 repeat-x #cdcdcd;   border:3px
> solid #fff;   cursor:pointer;     border-radius:9px;
>   -moz-border-radius:9px;     -webkit-border-radius:9px;
>   letter-spacing:-1px; } .button:hover {color:#ce0b0e;}
> 
> .button2 {    display:inline-block;   padding:5px 25px 9px;
>   font-size:22px;     line-height:27px;   color:#fff; 
>   background:url(button2-tail.gif) 0 0 repeat-x #cc2800;
>   cursor:pointer;     border-radius:6px;  -moz-border-radius:6px;
>   -webkit-border-radius:6px;  letter-spacing:-1px; } .button2:hover
> {background:#cc2800;}
> 
> .list-1 li {  font-size:14px;     line-height:19px;   font-style:italic;
>   padding:8px 0;      background:url(pic-1.gif) 0 bottom repeat-x; }
>   .list-1 a {color:#fff;}     .list-1 a:hover {color:#cc2800;}    .list-1
> .last-item {background:none;}
> 
> .list-2 li {  font-size:14px;     line-height:19px;   font-style:italic;
>   padding:8px 0;      background:url(pic-1.gif) 0 bottom repeat-x; }
>   .list-2 a {         display:inline-block;       color:#fff; 
>       padding-left:11px;          background:url(marker-1.gif) 0 8px no-repeat;
>   }   .list-2 a:hover {color:#cc2800;}    .list-2 .last-item
> {background:none;}
> 
> .link:hover {text-decoration:underline;} 
> 
> .link-1 {     display:inline-block;   font-size:14px; 
>   padding-right:8px;      background:url(marker-3.gif) right 8px
> no-repeat; } .link-1:hover {color:#fff;} 
> 
> .text-1 {     display:block;  font-size:19px;     line-height:45px;
>   color:#fff;     letter-spacing:-2px;    margin-bottom:5px; } 
> 
> dl span {float:left; width:82px; color:#fff;}
> 
> dl.years {line-height:35px;} dl.years dt {float:left; width:49px;
> color:#fff; background:url(pic-1.gif) left bottom repeat-x;} dl.years
> dd {overflow:hidden; background:url(pic-1.gif) left bottom repeat-x;}
> dl.years .last-item {background:none;}
> 
> .tdate-1 {    display:block;  width:60px;     height:60px;
>   overflow:hidden;    text-align:center;  background:url(time-bg.png) 0 0
> no-repeat;    float:left;     margin:0px 21px 0 0; }  .tdate-1 span {
>       display:block;      font-size:9px;      line-height:1.2em;      color:#fff;
>   }   .tdate-1 strong {       display:block;      font-size:37px;
>       line-height:46px;       color:#000;     }    /* -- gallery  begin --*/
> div.content img { position: relative; z-index: 2;}
> div.slideshow-container {     height: 378px;  width:600px;
>   margin-bottom:40px;     position:relative;  z-index:1;   } div.slideshow
> span.image-wrapper {  display: block;     width: 600px;   height: 378px;
>   position:absolute;  left:0;     top:0;  margin:0; } div.slideshow
> a.advance-link {  display: block;     margin: 0;  font-size:0;
>   line-height:0;  text-decoration:none; } div.slideshow
> a.advance-link:hover, div.slideshow a.advance-link:active,
> div.slideshow a.advance-link:visited {    text-decoration: none; }
> div#thumbs {  padding: 0;     width:600px; } ul.thumbs {  padding: 0 0 0
> 0;    width:100%;     overflow:hidden;    position:relative; } ul.thumbs li {
>   float:left;     margin-right:30px;  margin-bottom:30px;     width:180px;
>   height:124px; } ul.thumbs li.last {margin-right:0;} ul.thumbs
> li.last2 {margin-bottom:0;} ul.thumbs li.last3 {margin:0;}
> 
> a.thumb {display:block;} a.thumb:focus {outline: none;}
> 
> /* -- gallery end --*/
> 
> /***** contact form *****/
> #contact-form {width:600px;}
> #contact-form label {display:block; height:35px;}
> #contact-form label.message {height:324px;}
> #contact-form input {width:260px; font-size:14px; line-height:17px; color:#7f7f7f; padding:8px 20px 7px; margin:0; font-family:Arial,
> Helvetica, sans-serif; border:none; background:#fff;
> border-radius:6px; -moz-border-radius:6px; -webkit-border-radius:6px;}
> #contact-form textarea {height:314px; min-height:314px; max-height:314px; overflow:auto; width:560px; max-width:560px;
> min-width:560px; font-size:14px; line-height:17px; color:#7f7f7f;
> padding:5px 20px; margin:0; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
> border:none; background:#fff; border-radius:6px;
> -moz-border-radius:6px; -webkit-border-radius:6px;}
> 
> .buttons {padding-top:20px;} .buttons a {margin-right:10px;}      
> /****************************footer************************/ footer {
>   width:100%;     padding:30px 0 45px; }  footer span {display:block;}
> 
> .list-services {padding:19px 0 0 2px;}    .list-services li {
>       float:left;         padding:0 9px 0 0;  }   .list-services a {
>       display:block;      width:27px;         height:27px;        text-indent:-9999em;
>       background:url(social-icons.png) 0 0 no-repeat;     }   .list-services
> .item-1 a {background-position:-36px 0;}  .list-services .item-2 a
> {background-position:-72px 0;}    .list-services .item-3 a
> {background-position:-108px 0;}
```

Comment: No progress nor answer after 1 year. Perhaps this could be salvages?

Answer (score 0):

You have your `img` tags like this:

```
<img src="/banner-2.png" alt="">
```

Take off the bar in the `src`

```
<img src="banner-2.png" alt="">
```

Or if the images are inside folders add:

```
<img src="images/banner-2.png" alt="">
```

Comment: i just added them recently because i was trying to see if that could fix the problem but with or without it it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Tell me OP what format did you save those images in? Try saving those images in 24-bit PNG format and saving it without a color profile. Re-place your current not working images with the 24-bit ones see if that does the trick.